# Enum memberlist starts with number

Tags: vb.net, enums

I face a problem with an enum that I have built.

```
  Public Enum enumGraphType
    Table = 0
    Chart = 1
    Gauge = 2
    3DChart = 3
  End Enum
```

I get an error for 3DChart : Statement cannot appear within an Enum body. End of Enum assumed.
I know that I can use the name D3Chart but this is not what I want.
Also I know that I can add an attribute (like Description) and have my description as 3DChart, but this is not what I want.
Also I have tried [3DChart] and it doesn't work.
Is any way to work around that and keep the name?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enum members cannot start with numbers, so this is not valid:

```
3DChart = 3
```

You could prepend an underscore instead

```
_3DChart = 3
```

For what it's worth, you could add a description:

```
Public Enum EnumGraphType
    <ComponentModel.Description("Table")>
        Table = 0
    <ComponentModel.Description("Chart")>
        Chart = 1
    <ComponentModel.Description("Gauge")>
        Gauge = 2
    <ComponentModel.Description("3DChart")>
        _3DChart = 3
End Enum
```

Here's an enum-extension which returns it:

```
Public Module EnumExtensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function GetDescription(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
        Dim fi As Reflection.FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
        Dim attr() As ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute =
            DirectCast( _
                fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute), False),  _
                ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute() _
            )
        If attr.Length > 0 Then
            Return attr(0).Description
        Else
            Return EnumConstant.ToString()
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Now you get the description in this way:

```
Dim chartType = EnumGraphType._3DChart
Dim chartTypeDesc = chartType.GetDescription() ' 3DChart
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I was hoping for something smarter. Thank you Tim

Comment: @Nianios: You can have an Enum member prefix, such as `gt` (for GraphType), and put your numbers after that.

Comment: @Nianios: i have edited my answer to provide another way using a description.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks, I had already this solution. Good that you provide it here.